# Is optimization to move block inside both the block of a if-else branch correct?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, clang, llvm, barrier

Warning(Pseudocode)

Suppose we have a kernel :

```
def kernel(array):
   a = get_global_id(0)
   if a > 1:
      array[0] = 10
   barrier(LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)
```

Is it wrong for the code to get optimized like:

```
def kernel(array):
   a = get_global_id(0)
   if a > 1:
      array[0] = 10
      barrier(LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)
   else:
      barrier(LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)
```

Although this optimization doesn't look wrong, it yields incorrect results and data-races. I have looked some of the documentation provided by [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#noduplicate) , but still can't figure out why this is wrong? This is on intel x86 architecture and consider OpenCl implementation for barriers. Is there an issue if we call barrier from different locations in different threads?

Comment: What does `__attribute__((noduplicate));` in your link to the clang does have to do with anything?  What actual source language are you talking about, compiling for what target ISA?  Both versions are logically equivalent; if they're not working, that probably means neither version was actually safe but one of them just happened to work due to some quirk of how clang generated code.

Comment: They are logically equivalent, but that doesn't ensure that will work concurrently. This is on x86 on intel integrated gpu. I wanted to confirm if there is any synchronization issue  wrt barrier if they are called from multiple points in a program (Like for some threads, condition could be true, not for other threads). Consider the Opencl implementation of barriers.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about `barrier` like the [memory-barriers] tag you used, like C++ `std::atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` which limits reordering of this thread's accesses?  Or are you talking about `barrier()` as a synchronization primitive, where each caller waits for all threads to reach this before letting them all continue?   The tag for that is [barrier], and yeah it could potentially matter whether there are multiple call-sites if that means they're separate barriers.  But I'd have expected a deadlock if you have some threads waiting at one barrier, others at another.

Comment: I was referring to barrier as a synchronization primitive where it waits for everyone to arrive and then goes on from there. I get it now why this would be a deadlock but this is clearly wrong optimization that clang does so I pasted the `__attribute__((noduplicate))` that prevents it from doing that. But it still happens with that attribute so I should investigate more why it does that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I fixed the tag for you.  If you have an actual [mcve] where Clang mis-compiles something, you should show it as well or instead of pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have OpenCL barriers in if-else branches, even if both branches eventually call the barrier. All barriers must be outside of branching statements.